# Javascript(jquery), "pointer" to "'this' in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all and thank for responses :).
I have this code for modal image gallery

```
  var $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>");
  var $image = $("<img class='overlayImage'>");
  var $caption = $("<p></p>");
  $overlay.append($image);
  $overlay.append($caption);

  $(".galleryWrap").append($overlay);
  $(".galleryItem").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
    $overlay.show();
    var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("title");
    $caption.text(captionText);
      });
```

Lets say i want show next image in `$overlay.click()` function, something like :

```
$overlay.click(function()
var imageLocation = $(this).next().attr("href");
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
    $overlay.show()
```

Can i somehow point my new `imageLocation` variable to `.galleryItem` which was clicked in previous function, to get next sibling?
I know it can be probably done other way, just playing and trying to understand JS:)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simply make use of a global variable, which you assign to `this` on the click of `.galleryItem`? That would make the global variable the specific gallery item that is clicked on. Then you can just check what this global variable is in your second `click` function:

```
var selectedItem;
$(".galleryItem").click(function(event) {
  selectedItem = this; // selectedItem is now assigned to the specific .galleryItem
});
$overlay.click(function(event) {
  console.log(selectedItem); // Do something with selectedItem
});
```

This can be seen working in the following example:

```js
var selectedItem;
$(".galleryItem").click(function(event) {
  selectedItem = this; // selectedItem is now assigned to the specific .galleryItem
});
$("#overlay").click(function(event) {
  console.log(selectedItem); // Do something with selectedItem
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="galleryItem">One</div>
<div id="2" class="galleryItem">Two</div>
<div id="3" class="galleryItem">Three</div>
<br />
<div id="overlay">Overlay</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I wanted to avoid global variables, as it seems like something bad in JS. So in this example is best way to use it anyway? thank you very much for answer :)

Comment: The only thing bad about using global variables in JavaScript is that it can result in collisions. The benefit of global variables is that they have the same value across multiple functions, which is exactly what you want here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could move your display logic in the click handler, and use a global variable to maintain the state:

```
var $current = null;

$(".galleryItem").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $current = $(this);
    $overlay.show().click(); // trigger the click handler
});

$overlay.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var imageLocation = $current.attr("href");
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
    var captionText = $current.children("img").attr("title");
    $caption.text(captionText);

    $current = $current.next(); // point to next
    // ...etc
});
```